# Understanding the iOS documentation (cocoa touch) when referencing classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift

I was looking at the [Map Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/) documentation and it got me wondering why some classes are referred as objects. I know his may be a lack of knowledge on OOP in general but I need to ask.

For instance, this is how they are describing the MKDirections class in the [MapKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/) Reference.

- *An MKDirections **object** provides you with route-based directions data from Apple servers.*

And this is how they describe the MKDirectionsRequest class.

- *The MKDirectionsRequest **class** is used by apps that work with turn-based directions.*

Is there a reason why they couldn’t describe the MKDirections class in a similar fasion as the MKDirectionsRequest class? In other words something like...

- *The MKDirections **class** is used to provide you with route-based directions data from Apple servers.*

My main confusion comes because I was under the impression that you create an object as soon as you instantiate a class. In other words we know that an object will be created when using the MKDirections class so, why not call it class.

Sorry if my question doesn't make any sense but I’m curious if there is something I should be aware when reading the documentation and I come across these two different references, is there something special on the classes they describe as objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So in OOP classes *are* objects. The class objects are like blueprints, or printing plates, for instance objects which are created in the run of the program and actually perform the methods which are called. When a program loads, all of the class objects are initialized from the NSObject inheritance as a framework, which then allows you to create instance objects of all the basic types (or custom types if they're loading) during the run of the program. So the class objects are templates. But in filling out, say, a paper form, you don't want to fill out the template itself, you create a copy of it which you then fill out, leaving the template itself unchanged and available for further copying. This is the essential distinction between a class object and an instance of that object.

The difference between MKDirections and MKDirectionsRequest has to do with object inheritance. MKDirectionsRequest is what's called a subclass of MKDirections. The subclass object and its instances contains all of the properties and can perform all of the methods of its superclass, but can perform additional methods or properties outlined in its class profile. So an MKDirectionsRequest instance object is of the class MKDirectionsRequest which inherits from the MKDirections class.

Matt Neuberg's *Programming iOS 6* is available for free online (since it's outdated), but his early chapters on C-language inheritance and OOP orientation are still valid and very helpful. Here's a link to the section on Classes and Instances:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch02.html#_classes_and_instances

Comment: This is a very good explanation about OOP but I don't think it answers my specific question, unless I'm missing something. I know how inheritance works, I'm just curious as to why Apple make that distinction between classes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think Kim's answer about the additional class method `isDirectionsRequstURL:` is the likeliest reason for the distinction. I'm not familiar with the Map Kit Framework yet so I don't have working knowledge of it, sorry. And yeah, my reply was pretty general. It seemed like you were getting confused about the distinctions between class objects and object instances; sorry if I misread that.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the object is created by instantiating the class. Maybe the distinction is due to the fact that the MKDirectionsRequest class has a class method `isDirectionsRequestURL:`. MKDirections only has instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for the difference -- and I'm stretching here -- is that one of those classes has a class method while the other only has object/instance methods.  It **is** possible to use a `MKDirectionsRequest` class without creating an instance.  (`+ (BOOL)isDirectionsRequestURL:(NSURL *)url`)

It's more likely, though, to be a style difference.  If you assume that apps usually use classes by creating an instance of them first, the "class" description is functionally equivalent to the "object" one.

Comment: Hmm, you are probably right but I would expect the class method in the **MKDirections** since it is the one referred as *object* and you don't have to create an instance, also, if you look at the next two classes down **MKDirectionsResponse** and **MKETAResponse** they don't even have methods, only properties. Well I guess it doesn't really matter how they are referenced in the documentation as long as I'm not missing something crucial when reading the documentation I'm fine. Thanks a lot.